# Where is this Orchos Chaim and Ramban?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hagomel

The Tur writes in OC Siman 219 ("sif 6" in the newer prints) that if one didn't make the bracha of hagomel at the proper time, then they are still able to make the bracha whenever they'd like.

The Beis Yosef writes there that this is the "svarah" of the Tur but that  the Orchos Chaim writes in the name of the Ramban that one has until 3 days after they were required to make the bracha, to do so.

In the newer prints of the Tur-Beis Yosef there are often sources next to poskim that are brought down in the Bach, Beis Yosef, Prisha, etc. However in this case the printer did not write any source next to the Orchos Chaim or Ramban. Is it known where this is written in either the Orchos Chaim or Ramban that hagomel can be made until 3 days?

Comment: @msh Unfortunately, the Sefer OC (R' Aharon M'Lonil) in the Hebrewbooks program has a few pages missing in Hilchos Brachos http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23994&st=&pgnum=76 [page 76 ends in the middle of halacha *nun* and page 77 begins in the middle of halacha *nun zayin*. This is just where that halacha would fit in. (I do not have a hardcopy of the sefer).

Comment: Generally speaking, when the printers did not print the sources it is because they couldn't find it.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore [As he writes there at the end of halacha 55](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14070&pgnum=80), *Hagomel* is discussed in *Hilchos Krias HaTorah*. [Here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14070&st=&pgnum=46) is where he discusses it, and does not mention such a requirement.

Comment: @Ploni true..But what's interesting though is that the Beis Yosef is quoting a Orchos Chaim b'shem the Ramban and seemingly they didn't find a makor in either?

Comment: The proof is from the gemara in Eruvin 65 ,that the mind isnt settled until 3 days after travel. Meaning 3 days after travel is still considered traveling.

Comment: @sam the beis yosef brings that...im asking where is the source of the orchos chaim and ramban that say one has until 3 days?

Comment: Very good question, I did a Bar Ilan search on both and did not find anything, it could be they uses diff terms. Your best bet is to go through the Yabia Omer chelek 3:16 has a long teshuva on it,I am sure he addresses it,will go through the teshuva hopefully.

Comment: @sam A safe bet but, alas, he does not address the original source of Ramban, nor does he address it in his Chazon Ovadiah on Berachot.